# Is there a direct implementation of multiclass SVM in R(e1071)

Tags: svm

I have five classes and I want to use SVM(e1071 package) for the classification. I can see some good examples for binary classification using SVM, however,for Multiclass support, some members have suggested using either of One_Vs_Rest or One_vs_One binary classifier and then combine them to get the final prediction. Is there a direct implementation of Multiclass (either approach is fine for me) available?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now, I got the solution. I used the basic help file from the R and implemented the One_vs_One Multiclass using e1071 which is very short and to the point with clear comments in it.

```
library(xlsx)
library(gdata)
data(iris)
library(e1071)
library(caTools)

##---------- Split the overall dataset into two parts:70% for training and 30% for testing-----------
index_iris<-sample.split(iris$Species,SplitRatio=.7) 
trainset_iris<-iris[index_iris==TRUE,] 
testset_iris<-iris[index_iris==FALSE,] 
y <- testset_iris$Species

##---------- Now Create an SVM Model with the training dataset--------------------
model <- svm(Species ~ ., data = trainset_iris)
# print(model)
# summary (model)

##-------------Use the model to predict the test dataset so that we can find the accuracy of the model-----
pred <- predict(model,testset_iris)
table(pred, y)

##-------------- Compute decision values and probabilities--------------
pred <- predict(model, testset_iris, decision.values = TRUE)
attr(pred, "decision.values")
```